# Pass a ID of a TextBox to JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, autocomplete

I have page with Three textboxes with JQuery autocomplete feature I had hard coded the ID of the textboxes in the JQuery to do auto complete like

```
$(function () {
 $('["#txtDocType"],["#txtOtherType"],["#txtFormType"]').autocomplete({
     source: function (request, response) {
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "MyPage.aspx/MyWebMethod",
        data: "{'prefixText':'" + request.term.toLowerCase() + "', 
        'ddvId':'" + $(this).prop('id') + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
                 response(data.d);
                },
        error: function (result) {}
                 });
            },
            minLength: 1
        }); 
  });
```

is there a possiblity of passing the ID of the textbox to jquery during some event without hardcoding the ID of the textbox(I had googled it and seen so many pages but nothing helped)

Comment: you can even give a class to the three textboxes and you can use this single class in the Jquery function instead of three textbox id's

Comment: @AnoopJoshi is it like `$(".CommonclassName").autocomplete({...});`

Comment: I used the **Common Class name** in all the three Textboxes which AnoopJoshi and @harish had mentioned

Comment: @Jai By accessing it with **Common Classname** it Worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your html from this:

```
<input type="text" id="txtDocType" />
<input type="text" id="txtOtherType" />
<input type="text" id="txtFormType" />
```

to something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="txtDocType" class="my-text-box" />
<input type="text" id="txtOtherType" class="my-text-box" />
<input type="text" id="txtFormType" class="my-text-box" />
```

and update your javascript to something like this:

```
$(function () {
 $('.my-text-box').autocomplete({
     source: function (request, response) {
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "MyPage.aspx/MyWebMethod",
        data: "{'prefixText':'" + request.term.toLowerCase() + "', 
        'ddvId':'" + $(this).prop('id') + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
                 response(data.d);
                },
        error: function (result) {}
                 });
            },
            minLength: 1
        }); 
  });
```

Comment: Shouldn't the data be `data: {'prefixText':request.term.toLowerCase(), 'ddvId': this.id },`?